# Buttons on various panels

Tags: vb.net

I am having headaches with the following, I cannot pass buttons to other panels, my idea is that with the arrangement that I already have of buttons. Pass these created buttons to other panels that I am going to do, can someone help me please.

```
Dim botones(1, 3) As Button

Dim B As Button
Public Sub crearBotones()
    For filas As Integer = 0 To 1
        For columnas As Integer = 0 To 3
            B = New Button
            botones(filas, columnas) = B
            With B
                .Name = "" & filas.ToString & filas.ToString
                .Text = "" & filas.ToString & columnas.ToString
                .Left = 100
                .Location = New Point(40 + columnas * 70, 5 + filas * 70)
                .Height = 25
                .Width = 50
                Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(botones(filas, columnas))

            End With

        Next

    Next
End Sub
```

It is showing the buttons on one panel, I am looking for it to show the buttons on both panels.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "pass them to other panels"?  A control can only have ONE PARENT, so if you add them to a different panel, they will automatically be removed from their current panel.

Comment: If all the panels are in the same form, then simply make sure that your declaration `Dim botones(1, 3) As Button` is at FORM LEVEL and not inside a method.  Then they should be accessible from anywhere in that form's code.

Comment: I mean, the array already makes buttons for me, but I want to put the buttons on different panels, it's just letting me use it on one panel. In the panel that is in the for.

Comment: You need to assign the array with the new buttons  , after `End With` add `botones(filas ,columnas ) = B `

Answer (score 1):

> I mean, the array already makes buttons for me, but I want to put the
> buttons on different panels, it's just letting me use it on one panel.
> In the panel that is in the for.

Refactor the code just a bit so that your `crearBotones()` method receives a Panel as a parameter, and only creates the buttons if they have not already been created:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private botones(1, 3) As Button

    Public Sub crearBotones(ByVal pnl As Panel)
        For filas As Integer = 0 To 1
            For columnas As Integer = 0 To 3
                If IsNothing(botones(filas, columnas)) Then
                    Dim B As New Button
                    With B
                        .Name = "" & filas.ToString & filas.ToString
                        .Text = "" & filas.ToString & columnas.ToString
                        .Left = 100
                        .Location = New Point(40 + columnas * 70, 5 + filas * 70)
                        .Height = 25
                        .Width = 50
                    End With
                    botones(filas, columnas) = B
                End If
                pnl.Controls.Add(botones(filas, columnas))
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        crearBotones(Panel1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        crearBotones(Panel2)
    End Sub

End Class
```